# upgrading just_audio package in flutter

Tags: flutter, upgrade, just-audio

I'm encountering some errors after upgrading the just_audio package from `just_audio: 0.2.2` to  `just_audio: 0.6.5`. I have tried to change the code but failed. Here is a screenshot of my code; [image][image] 
 errors detail; [image][image][image]
Please help!

Comment: Hi, there can you tell some more about the error you are getting is your class and methods are not recognized by the editor?

Comment: Hello, the errors are only on just_audio package's methods/variables, maybe their are some upgrades in the package which causes these methods unrecognizable? I have added some more detail please have a look and let me know if you need any other detail. Thank you

Comment: Hi there it looks like that these arguments and methods are no longer maintained in the latest version I tried the example code of latest audio package and its working fine and the streams are now submethods of AudioPlayer. so you can use them as _player.playbackEventStream

Comment: yes you're right, I can use the playbackEventStream. But what about the other methods like AudioPlaybackState and position, what should I use to replace this?

Comment: Hi, you need to figure out manually in the API and documentation or by testing what methods are available or what is removed .either you can use the previous version which has all these methods. thanks

Comment: Actually the previous version 0.2.2 has some issues i.e. the app stuck on audio stop and sometimes the audio play button is not working, that's why I wanted to update to see if it solve my problem. Btw Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A lot will have changed between 0.2.x and 0.6.x so I will focus my answer on the specific error you showed concerning state.

In the new state model of 0.6.x, the state of the player consists of two orthogonal states called `playing` and `processingState`, as depicted in the following state diagram from the project README:

[image]

`playing` can be `true` or `false`, while `processingState` can be one of these states:

```dart
enum ProcessingState {
  /// The player has not loaded an [AudioSource].
  idle,

  /// The player is loading an [AudioSource].
  loading,

  /// The player is buffering audio and unable to play.
  buffering,

  /// The player is has enough audio buffered and is able to play.
  ready,

  /// The player has reached the end of the audio.
  completed,
}
```

One reason why this new composite state model was chosen is that in the old model, there was no way to distinguish between the following two states:

1. Buffering while playing.
2. Buffering while paused.

In the new model, these are easily distinguishable. If your app cares about both of these orthogonal states, you can listen to the `playingStateStream` which emits events encapsulating both states:

```dart
_audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
  if (state.playing) ... else ...
  switch (state.processingState) {
    case ProcessingState.idle: ...
    case ProcessingState.loading: ...
    case ProcessingState.buffering: ...
    case ProcessingState.ready: ...
    case ProcessingState.completed: ...
  }
});
```

Internally, `playerStateStream` is implemented by simply using rxdart to combine `playingStream` and `processingStateStream`. In more advanced scenarios, you may use a similar technique to combine any other streams your app is interested in all into one stream. If you have a good argument for making a particular combination of streams provided as a standard combination by the plugin, you are welcome to submit a feature request on GitHub.

Finally, since it appears you are also using audio_service, I would recommend looking at the latest audio_service example which demonstrates how to leverage the latest just_audio API to implement your background task in a more concise way.